# how can I ask a question again on qr-code in access and windows 7

Tags: ms-access, qr-code, windows-7-x64

my last question was deleted. yet people responded, thank you, and I followed their advices. I took the time to do it because of the holidays and the Covid. I still have one problem that I would like to outline.

with the QRCodeLib.xlam library, I create an impeccable qr-code ... unfortunately, I cannot call it from Access. see access code below :

```
    Public Sub GenQRCode()


Dim gxlApp      As Excel.Application
Dim gxlWB       As Workbook
Dim PAYLOAD_1   As String   ' chaîne de caractères à coder
Dim strFile     As String

strFile = "D:\QRCodeLibVBA-master\QRCodeLibDemo.xlsm"
PAYLOAD_1 = "SPC" & vbCrLf & _
        "0200" & vbCrLf & _
        "1" & vbCrLf & _
        "CH4431999123000889012" & vbCrLf & _
        "S" & vbCrLf & _
        "Robert Schneider AG" & vbCrLf & _
        "Via Casa Postale" & vbCrLf & "1268" & vbCrLf & _
        "2501" & vbCrLf & "Biel" & vbCrLf & _
        "CH" & vbCrLf & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "123949.75" & vbCrLf & _
        "CHF" & vbCrLf & _
        "S" & vbCrLf & _
        "Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder" & vbCrLf & _
        "Grosse Marktgasse" & vbCrLf & "28/5" & vbCrLf & _
        "9400" & vbCrLf & "Rorschach" & vbCrLf & _
        "CH" & vbCrLf & _
        "QRR" & vbCrLf & "210000000003139471430009017" & vbCrLf & _
        "Beachten sie unsere Sonderangebotswoche bis 23.02.2017!" & vbCrLf & _
        "EPD" & vbCrLf & "//S1/10/10201409/11/181105/40/0:30" & vbCrLf & _
        "eBill/B/41010560425610173"
        
Set gxlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
gxlApp.Visible = True
Set gxlWB = gxlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, False, False)
With gxlWB
    .gettxt (PAYLOAD_1)
    .qrCode
End With
If Not (gxlWB Is Nothing) Then
    gxlWB.Close False
End If
If Not (gxlApp Is Nothing) Then
    gxlApp.Quit
End If
Set gxlWB = Nothing
Set gxlApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

with the site https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/, I manage to create a qr-code in Access ... but all the line breaks are removed from the result. see access form code below. I create a form to create qr-code and a report to expose it.

```
    Private Sub btnCode2_Click()
         Call GetQRCode(Me.txtToCode, 150, 150)
    End Sub

    Sub GetQRCode(Content As String, Width As Integer, Height As Integer)
        Dim ByteData() As Byte
        Dim XmlHttp As Object
        Dim HttpReq As String
        Dim ReturnContent As String
        Dim EncContent As String
        Dim QRImage As String
        EncContent = EncodeURL(Content)

        HttpReq = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" & EncContent & "&size=" & Width & "x" & Height & ""

        Set XmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XmlHttp")
        XmlHttp.Open "GET", HttpReq, False
        XmlHttp.Send
        ByteData = XmlHttp.responseBody
        Set XmlHttp = Nothing

        ReturnContent = StrConv(ByteData, vbUnicode)
        Call ExportImage(ReturnContent)
    End Sub

    Sub ExportImage(image As String)

        On Error GoTo NoSave    
        m_FilePath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\qr.png"
        Open m_FilePath For Binary As #1
        Put #1, 1, image
        Close #1
       ' Build Export Path
       DoCmd.OpenReport "Table1", acViewPreview

    Exit Sub
   NoSave:
     MsgBox "Could not save the QR Code Image! Reason: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "File Save Error"
    End Sub

    Private Function EncodeURL(str As String)
        Dim ScriptEngine As Object
        Dim encoded As String
        Dim Temp As String

        Temp = Replace(str, " ", "%20")
        Temp = Replace(Temp, "#", "%23")
        EncodeURL = Temp
    End Function

    Private Sub Form_Load()
        Me.txtToCode.Value = "SPC" & vbCrLf & _
            "0200" & vbCrLf & _
            "1" & vbCrLf & _
            "CH4431999123000889012" & vbCrLf & _
            "S" & vbCrLf & _
            "Robert Schneider AG" & vbCrLf & _
            "Via Casa Postale" & vbCrLf & "1268" & vbCrLf & _
            "2501" & vbCrLf & "Biel" & vbCrLf & _
            "CH" & vbCrLf & _
            vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "123949.75" & vbCrLf & _
            "CHF" & vbCrLf & _
            "S" & vbCrLf & _
            "Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder" & vbCrLf & _
            "Grosse Marktgasse" & vbCrLf & "28/5" & vbCrLf & _
            "9400" & vbCrLf & "Rorschach" & vbCrLf & _
            "CH" & vbCrLf & _
            "QRR" & vbCrLf & "210000000003139471430009017" & vbCrLf & _
            "Beachten sie unsere Sonderangebotswoche bis 23.02.2017!" & vbCrLf & _
            "EPD" & vbCrLf & "//S1/10/10201409/11/181105/40/0:30" & vbCrLf & _
            "eBill/B/41010560425610173"
    End Sub
```

can someone help me?

Comment: The link in your question fails. Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/qrcode-image-generator.299675/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to convert the line breaks as well, like:

```
Temp = Replace(Temp, vbCrLf, "%0d%0a")
```

Comment: many thanks Gustav, it works. now i have to superimpose the swiss cross in the center of the qr-code. how to do it in VBA?

Comment: I can't find how to attach image files

Comment: As I understand it, this is on special request only: [QR codes with logo](http://goqr.me/qr-code-logo/), for a fee, and even for each code. Also, to some part, this relies on _error correction_.

Comment: I have to superimpose the Swiss cross on the qr-code of each invoice. is it not possible to do it by programming?

Comment: Perhaps, but I would start by doing it manually - having created the QR image with maximum error correction - and run carefully testing if the code can be read.

Comment: i create the qr-code with an ecc M as prescribed by post. I have it manually in Word center the Swiss cross on it and read it without problem. i tried to make a macro for this but the macro doesn't take image processing into account ... what can i do?

Comment: Expand your code to perform the image handling. That is, however, not so easy, as VBA isn't for that. You'll need a third-party control like [csXImage](https://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/default.asp). Example code and demo can be found on the site as well.

Comment: I found how to superimpose my two images : in the creation of the report, I place my two superimposed images then I fill the larger one with the qr-code and the smaller one with the Swiss cross. it works !

Comment: Click the large check mark under the up/down triangles to the left of the answer .